# Remove error bag in a specific field in Vee Validate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this script where it manually adds an error message in a specific field after I post a form via api

```
this.errors.add('registration-form.shipping_vmoney_email_address',response.data.message);
```

This is my HTML:

```
<input autocomplete="new-email" nofill v-model="shipping_vmoney_email_address" name="shipping_vmoney_email_address" v-validate="'required|email'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('registration-form.shipping_vmoney_email_address')}" type="text">
<span v-show="errors.has('registration-form.shipping_vmoney_email_address')" class="help is-danger has-text-left">{{ errors.first('registration-form.shipping_vmoney_email_address') }}</span>
```

My problem here is the error that I added via `this.errors.add`, when I type in the email address field the error doesn't remove, is there a way to remove the error of the email address field while i am typing?

Comment: Have you tried `this.errors.remove('registration-form.shipping_vmoney_email_address')`?

Answer (score 0):

your validation's configuration events need to changed. It's value should be **input**. In this when you are done typing with correct email address, message will be gone.

Something like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';

const config = {
    events: 'input'
};

Vue.use(VeeValidate, config);
```